# How to import into mongoDB connected data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I import data to mongoDB which has a lot of references? I know for `mongoimport`, but all I see I can do is specify collection.json such as

```
{ data: something }
{ data: something }
```

and import that with `mongoimport` with

```
./mongoimport -db dbname --collection collectionname --file collection.json
```

But, what if I need to import connected data?

For instance, let's say I want to load data into following models defined by mongoose Schema:

**user**:

```
var UsersScheme = new Schema({
    email: {type : String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    associations: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'associations'}],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UsersScheme);
```

And **associations:**

```
var AssociationsScheme = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required: true},
    members: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'users'}],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('associations', AssociationsScheme);
```

How to make some data loader without much of fuss? I know that I could programatically use promise (or generators) to save first association, without users, then users with that associations and then to update associations with created users. But, isn't there any other way with user of data-loader module or mongoimport itself?

I've tried so search for some fast data-loader module, but nothing I could find. Is programatically importing the best way I can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by highly connected data? Can you give an example?

Comment: Those relations don't actually exist in MongoDB. This is a Mongoose feature. It handles the queries for you. If you already have all the data dumped from other MongoDB instance (with all ids already set) then you can just import all those records in your new server.

Comment: Yes, I thought that ids will be the problem. However, thought maybe there's a way mongoimport solved it, but just couldn't find the way.